# Jquery DataTable :child row control error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

I have an HTML table that includes child rows. I want to make it like: [Data Tables JQuery](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html).

I want to put the table inside div that div is hidden and by clicking on button and show its but its not working!If div is shown its worked?!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to hide/show div that contains table on button click. Try this:

The button:

```
<button type="button" id="div-hider" class="btn btn-default">Hide/Show</button>
```

Div itself:

```
<div id="div-to-hide"
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
 $( "#div-hider" ).on( "click", function() {
     $("#div-to-hide").toggle();
 });
```

Comment: thank you but it`s not, i want to show JQuery DataTable with child row in Div. when Div is hide or show, jquery plugin is not work but if div is static display(always show) plugin is worked.

my problem is: why i use div with (display:none) DataTable plugin is not work?